# MYSQL SUM() returning top 10 values

Tags: mysql, database, select, sum

I am trying to find the SUM of 7 numeric fields to find the total, COMBINED with an output to display a LIMIT of 10 results ORDER BY total of each SUM.

Here is my SUM code, which works on its own, but I am unsure how to use the two queries together, keep getting syntax errors.

```
SUM(comfort + service + ambience + friendliness + spacious + experience + toilets)/(7)/COUNT(shop_id) AS total FROM ratings GROUP BY shop_id
```

This is my SQL query to return data normally:

```
SELECT * FROM pubs, services, ratings
WHERE pubs.shop_id=services.shop_id AND pubs.shop_id=ratings.shop_id
GROUP BY shop_name
ORDER BY shop_name ASC
```

I do not have the total of the 7 values stored in my database, I am using the above SUM query to find the total.     Thanks

Comment: You should select FROM a JOIN, not just a cartesian product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
SELECT pubs.*, services.*, sum(temp.total) as final_total FROM pubs inner join services on pubs.shop_id=services.shop_id
inner join (
select 
SUM(comfort + service + ambience + friendliness + spacious + experience + toilets)/(7) /COUNT(shop_id) AS total, shop_id FROM ratings GROUP BY shop_id
) as temp on pubs.shop_id=temp.shop_id
GROUP BY shop_name
ORDER BY final_total DESC, shop_name ASC
```

Comment: SUPERB! it works, am trying to understand the query now it works.. Thank you so much. I have pagination working with results, but now what i need is sort by field name and asc/desc. I am currently using a link to order by, would it be more effective to use jquery for ordering by, title, total, opentime   and ASC/DESC.  Am not having much success but could u recommend a suitable method please. thanks so much for the query code, I was fiddling with it for 4days now and was searching for the wrong information. thanks :)

Comment: I think you should make sorting on db side. But it's necessary to check that you have indexes by sorting fields otherwise it will be slow. Regarding jquery, it depends on amount of data that you store. Anyway at first you should check db solution.

Comment: sorry am confused, am using hiediSQL rather than phpadmin to access my database for editing, etc whilst I try to get things working.